# mongocxx insert current date with microsecond precision

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++17

I want to insert a mongodb datetime object with microsecond precision using the mongocxx c++ library. How can that be accomplished?

What I have so far:

```
auto final_doc = bsoncxx::builder::basic::document{};
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
final_doc.append(kvp("ts",bsoncxx::types::b_date(now));
```

but this leads to inserts with only seconds precision.

I know there is a `bsoncxx::types::b_date(...)` constructor for milliseconds, but not for microseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to insert a mongodb datetime object with microsecond precision*

That's impossible. JSON/BSON `Date` type is specified in ECMA-262 as a fixed format with millisecond precision:

> **[15.9.1.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) Time Values and Time Range**
>
> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC.
>
> **[15.9.1.15](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) Date Time String Format**
>
> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

If you want to store microseconds, you can store it as another type, e.g. `int64`.

```
auto final_doc = bsoncxx::builder::basic::document{};
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto now_us = now.time_since_epoch() / 1us;
final_doc.append(kvp("ts",bsoncxx::types::b_int64(now_us));
```

Comment: While the conclusion is correct, ECMA-262 has nothing to do with MongoDB server behavior. The relevant specification is http://bsonspec.org/spec.html which defines timestamps as the signed integer number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.